# Ember-data: loading one-to-one related model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I feel like I'm missing something really simple. I've created two models related to one another in a one-to-one relationship, each with `belongsTo('theOtherOne')`.

I have a route that loads a specific entry:

**Entry Model**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  word: DS.attr('string'),
  entry: DS.attr('number'),
  definition: DS.belongsTo('definition', {async: true}),
});
```

**Definition Model**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  body: DS.attr(),
  entry: DS.belongsTo('entry')
});
```

**Route**

```
model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('Entry', params.entry_id);
}
```

So, how do I make the related record available to my template? I'm pretty sure the relationship is configured correctly, since, in the Ember inspector, I can see that the "belongsTo" property is set, and when I click on it, the appropriate API call is made and loaded into the store. However, it is still not (apparently) available to the template.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know it's not available in the template? Have you tried putting `{{model}}` in the template corresponding to your route?

Comment: I can see in the Ember inspector that it hasn't loaded a "definition" and I can see that there hasn't been a network call to the API endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A probable solution would be to remove the `async: true` property from the `Definition` property of the `Entry` model:

```js
definition: DS.belongsTo('definition', {async: true}) // remove async: true
```

When async is set to true, Ember wont fetch the related entities until you actually request them. When set to false, Ember will fetch the related entities simultaneously with the entity requested.

In your current `Entry` model:

```js
word: DS.attr('string'),
entry: DS.attr('number'),
definition: DS.belongsTo('definition', {async: true}),
```

Ember Data is expecting a request for `Entry` to only return entries. The response would look something like:

```js
{
    entries: [
        {
            id: "e1",
            word: "foo",
            entry: 1,
            definition: "d1" // id for definition belonging to this entry
        },   
        {
            id: "e2",
            word: "bar",
            entry: 2,
            definition: "d2" // id for definition belonging to this entry
        },
    ],
}
```

To get the actual definitions you would need to make a second request.

However, if you make the relationship synchronous, then you would get both models in a single request with a response along the lines of:

```js
{
    entries: [
        {
            id: "e1",
            word: "foo",
            entry: 1,
            definition: "d1" // id for definition belonging to this entry
        },   
        {
            id: "e2",
            word: "bar",
            entry: 2,
            definition: "d2" // id for definition belonging to this entry
        },
    ],
    definitions: [
        {
         id: "d1",
            body: "abc",
            entry: "e1"      // id for entry belonging to this definition
        },
        {
         id: "d2",
            body: "def",  
            entry: "e2"      // id for entry belonging to this definition
        }
    ]
    
}
```

**EDIT (based on your comment)**

Since the two models are at different API points, you do need to make this relationship asynchronous and make two requests. Since Ember (and Ember Data) makes heavy use of promises, one way you could achieve this is by chaining promises ("thenables"):

```js
model: function() {
    var store = this.store;
    return store.find('entry').then(function() {  // success function, we got the entries so now we request definitions
        store.find('definition');
    }
}
```

If this code executes successfully, both entries and definitions will be loaded into the store and your route's model will be the array of entries.

**NOTE** The code above doesn't have proper error handling and just shows the essence of how to achieve this.

[Here's a good read on JavaScript promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)

[Ember's documentation on promises](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.Promise.html)

Comment: It didn't work. But Entries and Definitions are at two different API endpoints, so I *DO* want async, right?

Comment: Then in that case yes and you need to make a second request to obtain the definitions. Check out my edit.

Comment: Well, we're closer. I think your code has some scope issues (`this.store` within the `then()`) but I got closer with passing a variable `data` into the `then` function, and calling `data.get('definition')`. This loads the appropriate data into the store, but it doesn't return the whole thing as the model.

Comment: I fixed the scope issues. You don't need to pass anything into `then()`. Also what do you mean **the whole thing** as a model? Your model is `Entry` and if you want to get the definition you access it through `Entry`, for example, `var d = myEntry.definition`

Comment: Still no dice. 
Perhaps I have an error elsewhere in my code. Let me have a look for a bit,  do some reading, and I'll report back.

Comment: So, I started fresh with a project and everything works fine, now. In fact, with the async flag, you don't even have to make the second call, Ember will do it for you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: An added component to this (which, at points, may have been one of my issues) is that Ember will only load what it needs. i.e. if your template (or whatever) hasn't made use of the "belongsTo" item, it won't load it. Smart!